# Here my singing. What should I focus on improving?

Tags: voice

Here are two short examples of my singing from two months and two weeks ago. What should I focus on improving?

http://myeasywebaddress.com/Stage/MusicTheory/YesterdayBeforeAfter.mp3

Comment: I think you’ll do much better to find a teacher than try to use music.SE as your teacher.

Comment: ?...  Mr. Payne seems to offer a useful answer. (How can a question be good enough to get an answer with +2 votes but the question is -4?)

Comment: "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving."
(What should I focus on improving? What do you suggest?)

Answer (score 2):

You're improving!  Better tone, and you're no longer clipping off the ends of your notes.  Well done.

What will you be doing with your singing?   I'd like to hear you singing with music.  Several songs, in different styles.   Work on preparing those recordings.

Comment: Good. Thank you. I am presently focused on Yesterday (picking in the same style as Paul) and also Luka, Knights in White Satin and Fly Me to the Moon ... singing while playing guitar (I must say that has not been easy to combine with good awareness of both.)  I may also add bass.

Comment: When you add bass, try songs sung by bassists - that will give you 'limb' independence. Roxanne [even if you have to sing it an octave down], Boys are Back in Town...

Comment: I may also add bass (GUITAR).